How to mark the junction of two objects?
I need to use a geonode to mark the area of ​​mutual influence of the shader of one object on another when they intersect.  I tried ambient occlusion and was not happy with the result.  Raycast works better, but it doesn't take into account displacement from the shader.  Perhaps someone has encountered a similar problem and can suggest their own solutions?
